# pytest-bdd: how to get current scenario from @given?

Tags: python, pytest

I need to get scenario name or other unique information about currently running test in @given method.

In my test I declare, that I have some resource. This resource is being extracted/created from web api like that:

```
@given('I have a new article')
def new_article(vcr_fixture):
    with vcr_fixture.use_cassette('new_article'):  # I need to use different cassette name for different scenarios 
        return create_new_article()
```

The problem here is that I can have multiple scenarios with different parameters and I would like to use same resource multiple times. In this case I need different cassettes for each case. And I can't use those parameters for differentiating between cassettes, as they could be applied after the resource being created (for example, adding comments).
I tried to add request to the @given fixture, but could not find any unique information in it.

Answer (score 0):

To inspect your scenario name, you can use parsers.

```
from pytest_bdd import parsers
...

@given(parsers.parse('I have a {article_name}')
def new_article(vcr_fixture, article_name):
    with vcr_fixture.use_cassette(article_name):        
        return create_new_article()
```

Not sure if this if this answers your question, though..

Answer (score 0):

nAlthough what user2292262 suggested works, it doesn't work as one would have expected when start learning pytest-bdd (at least least what I'd have expected).

The solution AIUI is creating a fixture for each article you have among your tests, without automatisms (i.e. function that create for you the data you need dynamically).

This in a testing context should be reasonably doable, since the data set you have is not the real one, but a subset and the data you have as pre-reqs (the Given verbs) should be even less.
You can think of populate the fixtures with a script if this gets out of hand, by querying the DB and writing a templated file accordingly.

```
@given(parsers.parse('I have an article called foo')
def article_foo(vcr_fixture):
    with vcr_fixture.use_cassette('foo'):
         return create_new_article()

@given(parsers.parse('I have an article called bar')
def article_bar(vcr_fixture):
    with vcr_fixture.use_cassette('bar'):
         return create_new_article()


etc.
```

The problem in the 'factory' code of the other solution

```
@given(parsers.parse('I have a {article_name}')
def new_article(vcr_fixture, article_name):
    with vcr_fixture.use_cassette(article_name):        
         return create_new_article()
```

is that you are still tempted to use it as

```
Given I have an article called Foo
And I have an article called Bar
When I edit Foo
Then Bar is untouched
```

but this scenario won't work, because under the curtains you are actually using the same fixture twice but with different 'content'

In other words, with that code someone would 'new_article' for two 'data' instances. This goes against what pytest likes.

Also, from a purist point of view, the Given verbs in BDD should be facts, not things that create facts.